# Cannot import class from local modules in python

Tags: python

I have a module parser.py in local directory with

```
class Parser(object):
    . . . .
    . . . . 

class Parser2(object):
    . . . .
    . . . .
```

I'd like to import those in mainScript.py, however i'm getting an

> error no name 'Parser' in module parser

```
from parser import Parser
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't importing from [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html)?

Comment: no... I created my own Parser() class in parser.py (a local module)

Comment: If i rename the class, same issue :(

Comment: Can you `import parser`; is it just when you `from parser import Parser` that you get problems? Does `parser.__file__` give the expected location?

Answer (score 2):

Parser is [already a Python module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html). Rename your module (for example from "parser.py" to "myParseModule.py") and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: That's unlikely. If anything it is usually the other way round: local files shadow standard library ones.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I recreated the error and fixed it by renaming it from "parser.py" to something else.

Answer (score 0):

check your sys.path. if `/usr/lib/pythonX/lib-dynload` is before `''` you will be importing the official parser module from the standard library instead of your module.