# importing a class from another file

Tags: python, class, object, import

I have three different files and would like to use the class in one file in another file.

1) `__init__.py` (empty)

2) `assembler.py`

3) `parser.py` (this is where class Parser is located)

assembler.py:

```
from parser import Parser
file_location = r'C:\Users\location'
p = Parser()
print p.getCommands()
```

parser.py:

```
class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, file_location):      
        #get the files contents
        file = open(file_location,'r');
        self.contents = file.read();
        file.close();
        self.contents = self.contents.split('\n')
        self.contents = self.removeComments(self.contents)

    def removeComments(self, liste):
        remove = []

        for command in liste:
            if command == '':
                remove.append(command)
            if r'//' in command:
                remove.append(command)
            if not ('@' in command or ';' in command or '=' in command):
                remove.append(command)

        for element in remove:
            if element in liste:
                liste.remove(element)

        return liste

    def getCommands(self):
        return self.contents
```

I do get the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "assembler.py", line 1, in <module>
    from parser import Parser
ImportError: cannot import name Parser
```

I have tried researching this but not found a solution so far, hope you can help me.

Comment: [`parser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html) is a built-in module in Python, your script is importing that one.

Comment: `parser` is already the name of a Python module. You should give your module another name.

Comment: Possible duplicate (question/account): http://stackoverflow.com/q/24868635/3001761

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not demonstrate a basic understanding of python

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from .parser import Parser
```

this only works if you do not execute the script but use it as package.